# Regular expression to validate longitude and latitude using angulrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression for matching latitude/longitude coordinates that fall within the correct range. But the below code is giving error. Please let me know where I am going wrong:

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('latlong', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Valiadtion";
  $scope.lat = "latitude";
  $scope.long = "longitude";

  $scope.submit = function() {
    var lat = $scope.lati;
    var reg = /^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/;

    if (reg != lat) {
      console.log('error');
    }

  }
});
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QHe5mfMJOvHVu26TmX1j) is the Plunker

Comment: _“that fall within the correct range”_ - and which one would that be?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `==` you must use this

```js
var reg = /^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/;

var lat = "+90.0, -127.554334";

if (!lat.match(reg)) {
  console.log('error');
} else {
  console.log('passed!');
}
```

Read more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: I implemented your logic. But still, it's not working. @Saeed.Ataee

Comment: Can you give me an example?! @SRK

Comment: If a user gives the value it should accept Matches

+90.0, -127.554334
45, 180
-90, -180
-90.000, -180.0000
+90, +180
47.1231231, 179.99999999

Comment: I got it. @Saeed.Ataee

Comment: Good luck... ;)